# Array and array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, vuejs2

I have an array and an array of objects

```
'neededPermissions: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]',

'permissions:[{permissionType: 1, teamId: 1},{permissionType: 4, teamId: 1},{permissionType: 7, teamId: 1},{permissionType: 8, teamId: 1},{permissionType: 10, teamId: 1}]'
```

// route with neededPermissions array must include with the permissions in current user, then the user will have access to the route
// permissions.includes(neededPermissions)=true => user have access to the route

I know how it works for two arrays, but How to work with array and array of objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to do custom filteration based on array of objects,

```
let resultPermissions = permissions.filter((x)=>{ 
 return neededPermissions.includes(x.permissionType)
})
```

Comment: for the above example, resultPermission should return false, right? because permissions array does not have all the permissions in neededPermissions array.

Comment: you can apply negation in front of includes method result

Answer (score 0):

```
const permissions = [{permissionType: 1, teamId: 1},{permissionType: 4, teamId: 1},{permissionType: 7, teamId: 1},{permissionType: 8, teamId: 1},{permissionType: 10, teamId: 1}];
const neededPermissions = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11];
const validPermissions = permissions.filter((item) => {
    return neededPermissions.includes(item.permissionType);
});

// returned matched permissions
console.log(validPermissions);
```

Comment: So, can I check whether the validPermissions===neededPermissions, then router should go to certain page.  Will this work?  if (validPermissions === to.meta.neededPermissions) {
        router.push({path:'/somePage'})
       }

Comment: You need to make both data same. Array can't be compared like this. They share address  rather than value in assignment.  Another way can be:
let mappedValidPermissions = validPermissions.map((item) => { return item.permissionType; });
Now can be compared as below:
JSON.stringify(mappedValidPermissions) === JSON.stringify(neededPermissions);